# Function to use x amount of for loops in python 3

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I am currently working on a code decoder for fun and I managed to make a decoder of four letters or numbers in this form:

```
For w in string.printable:
    For x in ...:
        For y in ...:
            For z in ...:
                 If [w,x,y,z] = code :
                     Print (w,x,y,z)
```

What I would like is to have a function to make this possible for any amount of "for loops" layers for codes of any length. Is that possible?

Comment: I recall the very same question was asked and answered today already...

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: The only way I can think off of the top of my head, is creating a function in which you pass two iterables, and unpack those iterables when you need to use them in a for loop.

Comment: Do you have the link please?